# XML Parsing Error when getting query from perl script

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, cgi

I am new to Perl and I just copied the Cleb answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28992992/5553963) (and also made the ajax.pl executable) but it doesn't work and it gives this error:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///home/workspace/snmp-agent/query_ui/ajax.pl
Line Number 1, Column 2:
```

When I run the ajax.pl there is no error but when I get the query via Ajax I faced above error and as you can see from Cleb answer the first line is: "#!/usr/bin/perl".

Can someone please give me a hint how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CGI programs need to be executed by a web server (which has to be properly configured to execute CGI programs).

You are opening the file directly in a browser from the filesystem (we can tell because the `Location` is a `file:` scheme URL) and it is trying to parse it as XML (possibly you have associated `pl` files with the XML mime type in your OS somehow). Since it isn't XML, it fails.

Pick a web server, install it, and consult its manual on how to configure it to run CGI programs.

Comment: Thank you. As I said I am new to Perl, can you please introduce a server that I can install fast and with minimal config?

Comment: @AVarf For running a CGI script as a subprocess, [CGI::PSGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::PSGI) together with [plackup](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Plack/script/plackup) would be a good start IMO.

Comment: @AVarf — Apache HTTPD, Nginx, or Lighttpd

Comment: Just an update: I tried Lighttpd and Apache 2 both could ran the perl script but I couldn't send or receive messages (in Json format) so I just dropped it and used Flask and python could easily get the job done.